# Logging in a user with multiple application in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, single-sign-on

I have many applications wrote in Codeigniter 3, every application had different session cookie name, one day I try to build a simple Single Sign On over with them by myself. In my thought I just create one application again to handle the gate for authentication of the users, I pulled users table from other application into that one. I try to logged in there by set session name for every application, but when I try to get session value in each of application is blank, i checked in browser cookie, I have the session name, is there I'm missing here? I don't fully understand how global $_SESSION variable works, thank you.

Comment: We aren&#39;t mind readers... Questions without code aren't useful to anyone as it leaves too much to interpretation. Generally  if they are separate apps you won't be able to access the session from one another unless you use the same database and the session database driver.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't decide what code that I put on the questions, I use default session driver not database, so I need to use database driver?

Comment: are all these apps on the same server + domain?

Comment: yes, in same server and same domain..

Comment: well try to see if changing the session cookie name to the same name for all the apps works. kindof strange to have multiple ci apps on the same server, any reason why you don't just use one? (curious)

Comment: in the first place, each application has users table, so they can login independently, the application that handle single sign on (main login page) is built with native PHP, so in there I try set session of the codeigniter session, I mock the php session cookie from my native login page, so they as if logged in from its login page before that I has removed now. oh we maintain our server by ourself, we put all independent application in same server to cut the server bill.

Comment: native php sessions and codeigniter don't interface well. you'd have to load codeigniter session driver in the native php and use that for all your session stuff to use in both "php" and codeigniter. you might want to try not using the ci session library at all and just using regular session variables. in any case, the more information i get from you the more and more overly broad this is becoming, and the less i am able to follow.